# Python XOR hammingDistance

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

---

The problem is

> Given two integers x and y, calculate the Hamming distance.
>
> Note:
> 0 ≤ x, y < 231.

I tried to use the ^ operator and just count the number of 1s in the resulting str. However it did not pass all the testing cases. For instance. 93^73 returns `11188` when it's supposed to return something else.

Here is my code:

```
#hamming distance
class Solution(object):
    def hammingDistance(x, y):
        """
        :type x: int
        :type y: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        bin_x=int(bin(x)[2:])
    bin_y=int(bin(y)[2:])
    print(bin_x)
    print(bin_y)
    print(str(bin_x^bin_y))
    #.count('1'))
    hammingDistance(93,73)
```

Comment: nvm I should just do `return(str(bin(x^y)).count('1'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code here is incorrect: you should not convert the binary string into an integer (**certainly not using base 10**). For example, since `bin(16)[2:]` equals the string `'1000'`, you can see that `int(bin(16)[2:])` equals **the actual integer 1000**, which is not what you want!

In Python, the `^` operator for integers **already** does the looking at their binary representations for you. For example, in Python, `20 ^ 25` directly evaluates to `13`, the correct answer, because

- the binary representation of 20 is `10100`
- the binary representation of 25 is `11001`
- the binary representation of 13 is `01101`

Now you can finish your approach by using Python's `count` function to count the number of `1` characters in the string. For example, `'01101'.count('1')` evaluates to `3`.

Comment: Thanks!!! Haha. Actually, I looked up the document after lunch and realized that bitwise operators apply to int type as well just I just did `return(str(bin(x^y)).count('1'))`